# Certificate error when running setup_robot.sh

Tags: x509, google-cloud-robotics

When running `setup_robot.sh` per the [Cloud Robotics documentation](https://googlecloudrobotics.github.io/core/how-to/connecting-robot.html), the certificate is not valid. I get the following error:

```
Failed to update robot CR my-robot: Failed to get robot my-robot: Get https://www.endpoints.robco-skopecki.cloud.goog/apis/core.kubernetes/apis/registry.cloudrobotics.com/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/robots/my-robot: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not www.endpoints.robco-skopecki.cloud.goog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs if letsencrypt did not finish creating the certificate for the cloud-cluster. This might happend during a first time install. Here is how you can check:

```sh
kubectl get certificates cloud-robotics -o yaml
```

If the output lacks a status, restart the cert-manager:

```sh
kubectl delete pod cert-manager-<tab>
```

Once it restarted, check the `certificate` again and once the status is indicating sucess, you should have your certificate stored as a secret called `tls`:

```sh
kubectl get secrets tls
```

At this point you can rerun `setup_robot.sh`.